# Resolving ES module Error during Azure DevOps CI/CD pocess despite correct Sveltekit package.json configuration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, svelte, sveltekit

Here to ask your help on this very annoying issue I cannot seem to get rid of and is blocking me from deployment on Azure..

We have 2 steps in our CI/CD process: a build step and deployment step.

When I build my SK application in Azure Devops, download the artifact and run node index.js locally, I get this error:

```
Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension
```

But of course I have type module in the package.json, which looks like this and is present in the built artifact:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@skeletonlabs/skeleton": "^1.8.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.3.1",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.20.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.24",
    "postcss-load-config": "^4.0.1",
    "svelte": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "svelte-confetti": "^1.2.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">16.14"
  }
}
```

I am running node Node.js v20.1.0 and NPM v9.6.4. This is driving me nuts as I cannot see anything that might be the culprit here...

For completeness, here is my build pipeline:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '16.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present
        npm run test --if-present
      displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop
```

Any clues or hints? Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your application code in the working directory where you're running `npm install`? Also, you say you're using Node.js v20.1.0, but you're installing Node 16. Why are you configuring your build environment differently from your development environment?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed the post as I made a mistake: the build is done in the pipeline (npm run build) so the artifact shouldnt need NPM install. What I did, is download the build artifact and try to run node index.js in it which is trowing the ES module error.